# Moshi/Kotlin - How to serialize NULL JSON strings into empty strings instead?

Tags: json, null, kotlin, moshi

I'm trying to write a null-safe String adapter that will serialize this JSON `{"nullString": null}` into this: `Model(nullString = "")` so that any JSON with a 'null' value that I expect to be a String will be replaced with `""` (assuming there exists a data class like this: `data class Model(val nullString: String)`)

I wrote a custom adapter to try and handle this:

```
class NullStringAdapter: JsonAdapter<String>() {
    @FromJson
    override fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader?): String {
        if (reader == null) {
            return ""
        }

        return if (reader.peek() == NULL) "" else reader.nextString()
    }

    @ToJson
    override fun toJson(writer: JsonWriter?, value: String?) {
        writer?.value(value)
    }
}
```

...in an attempt to solve this parsing error:

`com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException: Expected a name but was NULL at path $.nullString`

Moshi parsing code:

```
val json = "{\"nullString\": null}"

val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .add(NullStringAdapter())
    .build()

val result = moshi.adapter(Model::class.java).fromJson(configStr)
```

What am I missing here? Still new to moshi so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The immediate problem is the missing `reader.nextNull()` call to consume the null value.

There are a couple other cleanup things you can do here, too.
With `@FromJson`, implementing `JsonAdapter` is unnecessary.
Also, the JsonReader and JsonWriter are not nullable.

```
object NULL_TO_EMPTY_STRING_ADAPTER {
  @FromJson fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader): String {
    if (reader.peek() != JsonReader.Token.NULL) {
      return reader.nextString()
    }
    reader.nextNull<Unit>()
    return ""
  }
}
```

and use add the adapter:

```
val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(NULL_TO_EMPTY_STRING_ADAPTER)
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()
```